# выборка из 3 таблиц с объединением данных

Tags: sql, выборка

Добрый вечер,
имеется проблема, которую никак не могу решить.
Существует 3 таблицы:

1. tm_posts - данные о постах и страницах
2. tm_attributes - данные о тегах и категориях
3. tm_relationships - связи 1 и 2 таблицы

Пример структуры:

```
tm_posts:      

id | name | text
-------------------
1  | kols | <ТЕКСТ>
2  | ando | <ТЕКСТ>
3  | krot | <ТЕКСТ>

tm_attributes:    

id | sign | attr_name
-------------------
1  | tag  | учебник
2  | tag  | дождь
3  | cat  | личное
4  | cat  | опыт

tm_relationships:  

id | id_attr | id_post
-------------------
1  |    1    | 2
2  |    2    | 2
3  |    3    | 2
4  |    4    | 2
```

Мне нужно получить такой результат по нику ando:

```
id | name |  text   |      tags     |    category   |
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | ando | <ТЕКСТ> | учебник,дождь |  личное,опыт  |
```

Т.е. берутся данные из таблицы tm_posts по нику ando, ищется связка тегов и категорий по id поста в таблице tm_relationships. После чего получаем данные из таблицы tm_attributes. Эти данные сливаем в строку.

Вот что получилось сделать:

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.attr_name) As `tags`
FROM tm_posts t1
JOIN tm_relationships t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_post
JOIN tm_attributes t3 ON t3.id = t2.id_attr
WHERE t1.name= 'ando'
AND t3.sign = 'tag'
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Этот код выводит все, кроме категорий. Как мне сюда добавить еще и категории.

-----------------------------Добавлено:

Необходимо выбрать все записи из БД с категорией "личное", но при этом к каждой записи нужно приклеить колонку со связкой тегов.

Структура таблиц остается такая же.
Результат должен выдать, примерно такой:

```
id | name |   text  |      tags       |      category     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | ando | <ТЕКСТ> | учебник,дождь   |       личное      |
5  | ник  | <ТЕКСТ> | какие-то теги   |       личное      |
6  | ник  | <ТЕКСТ> | какие-то теги   |       личное      |
```

Т.е. выбрались все записи с тегами, но только с определенной категорией "личное"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю можно сделать два join к tm_attributes 
наподобие

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.attr_name) As `tags`,GROUP_CONCAT(t4.attr_name) As `cats`
FROM tm_posts t1
JOIN tm_relationships t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_post
left JOIN tm_attributes t3 ON t3.id = t2.id_attr and t3.sign = 'tag'
left JOIN tm_attributes t4 ON t4.id = t2.id_attr and t4.sign = 'cat'
WHERE t1.name= 'ando'

GROUP BY t1.id
```

Для выбора только категории личное пришел в голову только такой запрос [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a936/10):

1)  сначала выбираем все Post с категория личное

2) делаем join к категориям

```
    select cat_data.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.attr_name) As `tags` from (select t1.*,t4.attr_name from tm_attributes t4 
join tm_relationships t2 on id_attr=t4.id 
join tm_posts t1 on id_post=t1.id
where t4.sign = 'cat' and t4.attr_name='личное' ) cat_data
join tm_relationships t2 on id_post=cat_data.id
left JOIN tm_attributes t3 ON t3.id = t2.id_attr and t3.sign = 'tag'
group by cat_data.id
```

Comment: Поправил ответ и добавил ссылку на fiddle

Comment: Ого, спасибо огромное! 
Я бы до такого запроса не додумался, тяжело.
Все работает как надо!

Я сделал тоже запрос, переставив таблицы местами, все выводит как надо, однако поле Tags выводит все существующие теги.
Если вдруг вам интересно - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d0b3/1

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(if(t3.sign='tag',t3.attr_name,NULL)) As `tags`,
             GROUP_CONCAT(if(t3.sign='cat',t3.attr_name,NULL)) As `cats`
  FROM tm_posts t1
  JOIN tm_relationships t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_post
  JOIN tm_attributes t3 ON t3.id = t2.id_attr
 WHERE t1.name= 'ando'
   AND t3.sign in('tag','cat')
 GROUP BY t1.id
```

Условие `t3.sign in('tag','cat')` можно убрать, если кроме tag и cat нет других видов и не предвидится. И tm_relationships думаю стоит клеить по LEFT JOIN, в случае, если у какой то статьи может не быть ни тегов ни категорий.

Comment: @Batanichek `group_concat` есть только в MySQL так что выбор БД очевиден. В оракле if заменить на decode или для совместимости с другими БД на case

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Этот вариант будет работать быстрее чем с двумя join tm_attributes?

Comment: @Павел да. хотя думаю разница будет достаточно мала